# Pivot Table VBA shows Compile Error when I had it working before

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

When I try to run the Macro it highlights the "End Sub" Statement at the bottom of the screen and shows the error "Unexpected end with" and will highlight the "End Sub" below releasing object memories. No matter What I try it will not go away and I had the macro working before this error occurred. Is there any way to fix this?

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPT As Worksheet

Sub create_pivot_table()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Call Delete_PT_Sheet

With wsData
   LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))  
   Set wsPT = wb.Worksheets.Add
   wsPT.Name = "P&C"
   Set PTCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, DataRange)
   Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(wsPT.Range("A1"), "PC_Sales")
 With PT '??????

End With

'//Releasing Object Memories

Set PT = Nothing

Set PTCache = Nothing

Set wsPT = Nothing

Set DataRange = Nothing

Set wsData = Nothing

Set wb = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Delete_PT_Sheet()

On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wb.Worksheets("Pivot Table").Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing an `End With`.

Comment: 2 With, 1 End With.  Think of them as separate blocks.

Comment: You have `With PT` inside the `With wsData ... End With`, which is not allowed without `End With`... Since, nothing follows it, probably it remained there by mistake. Try writing the code more compact. Otherwise, we cannot understand too much. I tried compacting it a little and only during this operation I could easily see your problem.

Comment: Thank you all!!!!! My first time on this website and you have all been so helpful!